# Image Size in IE6 in Percent of Parent Element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I need IE6 support. My client is still using this "very good" browser. So, I need to make responsive table with images.

My `table` has 12 images. Its width is set to `100%` and its `td` elements have a width of `8.33%`. Images' width is `100%`. In all normal browsers it works good. Images are bigger or smaller in different screens. But in IE6-IE9 images' width is their real width. And table is too wide. I see the horizontal scroll in my page and its very lamentable:

```css
td.footer table td {
    width: 8.333333333333333%;
    padding: 1px;
}

.footer table td img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/1.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m1.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/2.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m2.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/3.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m3.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/4.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m4.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/5.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m5.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/6.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m6.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/7.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m7.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/8.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m8.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/9.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m9.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/10.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m10.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/11.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m11.jpg"></a></td>
    <td class="banner_t"><a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/12.jpg" rel="lightbox['q']"><img class="banner" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/m12.jpg"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For responsive design you use media queries, so IE9 and greater http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: @waldemar Where did he get his stats from, 2005? Maybe you should point him to this: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown

Comment: Show him this website, it states that less than 0.1% of Americans use the browser, with the highest usage being between 10% and 20% of the country's total. His information is wrong, educate him. https://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown

Comment: try adapt this stuff - http://adapt.960.gs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a *responsive table*, but it appears as though you want a table that is always 100% the width of the viewport, and images/links that are 100% the width of their parent table cell. If that's the case, you really don't need much more than a fixed table layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Glorious IE6</title>
        <style type="text/css">/* styles below */</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="image.png" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="image.png" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="image.png" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="image.png" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The styles are pretty basic. First we change the `table-layout` to that of `fixed`. This appears to be the main ingredient in the solution. You can read more about the [`fixed` option here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Essentially, it sets the width of each cell as a fraction of the total width of the table. Additional instructions include reducing padding and borders, as well as making nested links and images size themselves according to their parents width:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td {
    padding: 0;
}

a, img {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    display: block;
}
```

The end-result appears to be the effect you're attempting to achieve:

[image]